# PHP - prevent users from accessing the files of other users- just tell me what are steps please?

Tags: php, session

I have searched for this subject and I cannot find the answer.
I am developing a software in PHP.

In this software, the user logs in and uploads files. After that they can logout. My question is:

**how can I prevent other users from accessing the files of another user?**

I use sessions for login users.

example:
user a logs in. php set session for this user. user a uploads a file, PHP moves the file to a specific folder. user a logouts.

user b logs in. php sets session for this user. user b can't access the files that user a uploads.

**how can I write php code to enforce this?**

thanks

Comment: Are you using a DB as well?

Comment: store the filename and uploader in a database, then search for files where they're the owner

Comment: thanks.yes I use DB.  a question: if a user type: http:\\www.domain.com\somefolder\afile.jpg in browser can access this file without permission. right? how can i prevent from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of storing files in a public area like `"http:\\www.domain.com\somefolder\afile.jpg"` you have to save them in a protected place which only is readable by the server, then to presenting files to any client, you need a Gate that validates users, gets requested file name and users sessions, then give them a copy of file with a temporary address.

Comment: thanks. if I use this method while my software use a temporary address for a file, this file is reachable for every one by typing this temporary address in address bar and this isn't secure. I want to use a secure method. thank you.

Comment: I find solution now. I can use sample.php instead of source of img files or for download a files by user set a header by php. thanks. answer of @payam sbr  is good between other answer so i tick it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a table for uploaded files with the column of the uploader, like the following

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS files (
    filename VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    uploader VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)
```

after user login you get the username from the `$_SESSION` query the db with something like

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE uploader = $username
```

Comment: thanks. a question: if a user type: http:\\www.domain.com\somefolder\afile.jpg in chrome can access this file without permission. right? how can i prevent from this?